# How to run Arquillian tests with IntelliJ IDEA and Wildfly Swarm

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-swarm

I try to follow how-to guide at 
https://howto.wildfly-swarm.io/v/2017.5.0/test-in-container/

They wrote:

> Since Arquillian is simply an integration with JUnit, you can run your
>   test by using Maven or your IDE:

When I run the DatasourcesIT#testIt from IDEA with

- Arquillian Junit Manual container configuration
- or with plain Junit

I got failed test.

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :Found the datasource
Actual   :
```

But this test works when I run `mvn verify`

Why?
May be I missed something in Arquillian Junit Manual container configuration?
I don't add something in manual configuration.

**Edit 1**

Add logs, but these are very similar.

Maven log:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.wildfly.swarm.howto.datasources.DatasourcesIT
May 04, 2017 9:49:11 PM org.jboss.arquillian.drone.webdriver.factory.remote.reusable.ReusedSessionPermanentFileStorage readStore
INFO: Reused session store is not available at /home/ar/.drone-webdriver-session-store, a new one will be created.
May 04, 2017 9:49:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: executable: /home/ar/projects/github/wildfly-swarm-howto/use-a-bom/target/drone-phantomjs
May 04, 2017 9:49:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: port: 21610
May 04, 2017 9:49:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: arguments: [--webdriver=21610, --webdriver-logfile=/home/ar/projects/github/wildfly-swarm-howto/use-a-bom/phantomjsdriver.log]
May 04, 2017 9:49:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: environment: {}
[INFO  - 2017-05-04T18:49:13.840Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 21610
[INFO  - 2017-05-04T18:49:14.138Z] Session [5e5f4a70-30fa-11e7-bf4c-6fea2c273ecf] - page.settings - {"XSSAuditingEnabled":false,"javascriptCanCloseWindows":true,"javascriptCanOpenWindows":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"loadImages":true,"localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled":false,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1","webSecurityEnabled":true}
[INFO  - 2017-05-04T18:49:14.138Z] Session [5e5f4a70-30fa-11e7-bf4c-6fea2c273ecf] - page.customHeaders:  - {}
[INFO  - 2017-05-04T18:49:14.138Z] Session [5e5f4a70-30fa-11e7-bf4c-6fea2c273ecf] - Session.negotiatedCapabilities - {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"2.1.1","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.2.0","platform":"linux-unknown-64bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}
[INFO  - 2017-05-04T18:49:14.138Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: 5e5f4a70-30fa-11e7-bf4c-6fea2c273ecf
[INFO  - 2017-05-04T18:49:14.709Z] ShutdownReqHand - _handle - About to shutdown
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.181 sec - in org.wildfly.swarm.howto.datasources.DatasourcesIT

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

IDEA log:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Dphantomjs.binary.version=2.1.1 -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:/opt/Jetbrains/idea-IU-171.4073.17/lib/idea_rt.jar=44397:/opt/Jetbrains/idea-IU-171.4073.17/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /opt/Jetbrains/idea-IU-171.4073.17/lib/idea_rt.jar:/opt/Jetbrains/idea-IU-171.4073.17/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/ar/projects/github/wildfly-swarm-howto/use-a-bom/target/test-classes:/home/ar/projects/github/wildfly-swarm-howto/use-a-bom/target/classes:/home/ar/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.187/h2-1.4.187.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/jaxrs/2017.6.0-SNAPSHOT/jaxrs-2017.6.0-20170504.101939-7.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/container/2017.6.0-SNAPSHOT/container-2017.6.0-20170504.101836-7.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/spi/2017.6.0-SNAPSHOT/spi-2017.6.0-20170504.101825-7.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.2.Final/jandex-2.0.2.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/bootstrap/2017.6.0-SNAPSHOT/bootstrap-2017.6.0-20170504.101815-7.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/modules/jboss-modules/1.5.2.Final/jboss-modules-1.5.2.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/config-api/1.0.3.Final/config-api-1.0.3.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/config-api-runtime/1.0.3.Final/config-api-runtime-1.0.3.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/logging/2017.6.0-SNAPSHOT/logging-2017.6.0-20170504.101843-7.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/undertow/2017.6.0-SNAPSHOT/undertow-2017.6.0-20170504.101921-7.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/io/2017.6.0-SNAPSHOT/io-2017.6.0-20170504.101850-7.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/ee/2017.6.0-SNAPSHOT/ee-2017.6.0-20170504.101908-7.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/naming/2017.6.0-SNAPSHOT/naming-2017.6.0-20170504.101902-7.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/enterprise/concurrent/jboss-concurrency-api_1.0_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-concurrency-api_1.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/interceptor/jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/el/jboss-el-api_3.0_spec/1.0.7.Final/jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.7.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/javax.el-impl/3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1/javax.el-impl-3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/request-controller/2017.6.0-SNAPSHOT/request-controller-2017.6.0-20170504.101913-7.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-jboss/2.0.0-alpha-9/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-jboss-2.0.0-alpha-9.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-jboss/2.0.0-alpha-9/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-jboss-2.0.0-alpha-9.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-javaee/2.0.0-alpha-9/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-javaee-2.0.0-alpha-9.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base/2.0.0-alpha-9/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base-2.0.0-alpha-9.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee/2.0.0-alpha-9/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee-2.0.0-alpha-9.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-base/2.0.0-alpha-9/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-base-2.0.0-alpha-9.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/servlet/jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/websocket/jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec/1.1.1.Final/jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/io/undertow/undertow-servlet/1.4.11.Final/undertow-servlet-1.4.11.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/io/undertow/undertow-core/1.4.11.Final/undertow-core-1.4.11.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/xnio/xnio-api/3.3.6.Final/xnio-api-3.3.6.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/xnio/xnio-nio/3.3.6.Final/xnio-nio-3.3.6.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/security/2017.6.0-SNAPSHOT/security-2017.6.0-20170504.101926-7.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/annotation/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/jaxrs-cdi/2017.6.0-SNAPSHOT/jaxrs-cdi-2017.6.0-20170504.101931-7.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-all/5.0.4/asm-all-5.0.4.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/ws/rs/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.7.4/jackson-core-2.7.4.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.7.4/jackson-annotations-2.7.4.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.7.4/jackson-databind-2.7.4.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.7.4/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.7.4.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-base/2.7.4/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.7.4.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/2.7.4/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.7.4.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/meta-spi/2017.6.0-SNAPSHOT/meta-spi-2017.6.0-20170504.101820-7.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/datasources/2017.6.0-SNAPSHOT/datasources-2017.6.0-20170504.093822-6.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/jca/2017.6.0-SNAPSHOT/jca-2017.6.0-20170504.093815-6.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/connector/2017.6.0-SNAPSHOT/connector-2017.6.0-20170504.093806-6.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/resource/jboss-connector-api_1.7_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-connector-api_1.7_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/transactions/2017.6.0-SNAPSHOT/transactions-2017.6.0-20170504.093739-6.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/narayana/jts/narayana-jts-idlj/5.3.3.Final/narayana-jts-idlj-5.3.3.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/openjdk-orb/openjdk-orb/8.0.4.Final/openjdk-orb-8.0.4.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/ironjacamar/ironjacamar-jdbc/1.3.4.Final/ironjacamar-jdbc-1.3.4.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/junit/arquillian-junit-container/1.1.12.Final/arquillian-junit-container-1.1.12.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/junit/arquillian-junit-core/1.1.12.Final/arquillian-junit-core-1.1.12.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/test/arquillian-test-api/1.1.12.Final/arquillian-test-api-1.1.12.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/core/arquillian-core-api/1.1.12.Final/arquillian-core-api-1.1.12.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/test/arquillian-test-spi/1.1.12.Final/arquillian-test-spi-1.1.12.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/core/arquillian-core-spi/1.1.12.Final/arquillian-core-spi-1.1.12.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/container/arquillian-container-test-api/1.1.12.Final/arquillian-container-test-api-1.1.12.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-api/1.2.6/shrinkwrap-api-1.2.6.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/container/arquillian-container-test-spi/1.1.12.Final/arquillian-container-test-spi-1.1.12.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/container/arquillian-container-spi/1.1.12.Final/arquillian-container-spi-1.1.12.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/core/arquillian-core-impl-base/1.1.12.Final/arquillian-core-impl-base-1.1.12.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/test/arquillian-test-impl-base/1.1.12.Final/arquillian-test-impl-base-1.1.12.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/container/arquillian-container-impl-base/1.1.12.Final/arquillian-container-impl-base-1.1.12.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/config/arquillian-config-api/1.1.12.Final/arquillian-config-api-1.1.12.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/config/arquillian-config-impl-base/1.1.12.Final/arquillian-config-impl-base-1.1.12.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi/2.0.0-alpha-9/shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi-2.0.0-alpha-9.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/container/arquillian-container-test-impl-base/1.1.12.Final/arquillian-container-test-impl-base-1.1.12.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-impl-base/1.2.6/shrinkwrap-impl-base-1.2.6.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-spi/1.2.6/shrinkwrap-spi-1.2.6.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/graphene/graphene-webdriver-api/2.1.0.Alpha2/graphene-webdriver-api-2.1.0.Alpha2.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/graphene/graphene-webdriver-spi/2.1.0.Alpha2/graphene-webdriver-spi-2.1.0.Alpha2.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/graphene/graphene-webdriver-impl/2.1.0.Alpha2/graphene-webdriver-impl-2.1.0.Alpha2.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/extension/arquillian-drone-impl/2.0.1.Final/arquillian-drone-impl-2.0.1.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/extension/arquillian-drone-configuration/2.0.1.Final/arquillian-drone-configuration-2.0.1.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/cglib/cglib/2.2.2/cglib-2.2.2.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.3.1/asm-3.3.1.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/1.2/objenesis-1.2.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/extension/arquillian-drone-api/2.0.1.Final/arquillian-drone-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/extension/arquillian-drone-spi/2.0.1.Final/arquillian-drone-spi-2.0.1.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/extension/arquillian-drone-webdriver/2.0.1.Final/arquillian-drone-webdriver-2.0.1.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-api/2.53.1/selenium-api-2.53.1.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/19.0/guava-19.0.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-support/2.53.1/selenium-support-2.53.1.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-chrome-driver/2.53.1/selenium-chrome-driver-2.53.1.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/2.53.1/selenium-firefox-driver-2.53.1.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.3/commons-exec-1.3.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-ie-driver/2.53.1/selenium-ie-driver-2.53.1.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna-4.1.0.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/4.1.0/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-remote-driver/2.53.1/selenium-remote-driver-2.53.1.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/cglib/cglib-nodep/2.1_3/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.1/httpclient-4.5.1.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.3/httpcore-4.4.3.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/htmlunit-driver/2.20/htmlunit-driver-2.20.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/htmlunit/2.20/htmlunit-2.20.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.2/xalan-2.7.2.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/xalan/serializer/2.7.2/serializer-2.7.2.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.2/httpmime-4.5.2.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/htmlunit-core-js/2.17/htmlunit-core-js-2.17.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.11.0/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/nekohtml/nekohtml/1.9.22/nekohtml-1.9.22.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/cssparser/cssparser/0.9.18/cssparser-0.9.18.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/w3c/css/sac/1.3/sac-1.3.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-client/9.2.15.v20160210/websocket-client-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.2.15.v20160210/jetty-util-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.2.15.v20160210/jetty-io-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-common/9.2.15.v20160210/websocket-common-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-api/9.2.15.v20160210/websocket-api-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/com/opera/operadriver/1.5/operadriver-1.5.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/com/opera/operalaunchers/1.1/operalaunchers-1.1.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.4.1/protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/commons-jxpath/commons-jxpath/1.3/commons-jxpath-1.3.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/ini4j/ini4j/0.5.2/ini4j-0.5.2.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/arquillian/extension/arquillian-phantom-driver/1.2.1.Final/arquillian-phantom-driver-1.2.1.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/com/codeborne/phantomjsdriver/1.2.1/phantomjsdriver-1.2.1.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/resolver/shrinkwrap-resolver-api/2.2.4/shrinkwrap-resolver-api-2.2.4.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/resolver/shrinkwrap-resolver-spi/2.2.4/shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-2.2.4.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/resolver/shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven/2.2.4/shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven-2.2.4.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/resolver/shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-maven/2.2.4/shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-maven-2.2.4.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/resolver/shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven-archive/2.2.4/shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven-archive-2.2.4.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/resolver/shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven/2.2.4/shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-2.2.4.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-api/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-api-1.0.0.v20140518.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-impl/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-impl-1.0.0.v20140518.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-spi/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-spi-1.0.0.v20140518.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-util-1.0.0.v20140518.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-connector-basic/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-connector-basic-1.0.0.v20140518.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-transport-wagon/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-transport-wagon-1.0.0.v20140518.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-aether-provider/3.2.5/maven-aether-provider-3.2.5.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-model/3.2.5/maven-model-3.2.5.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-model-builder/3.2.5/maven-model-builder-3.2.5.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/3.2.5/maven-repository-metadata-3.2.5.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/3.2.5/maven-settings-3.2.5.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-settings-builder/3.2.5/maven-settings-builder-3.2.5.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.21/plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.20/plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-provider-api/2.6/wagon-provider-api-2.6.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-file/2.6/wagon-file-2.6.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-lightweight/2.6/wagon-http-lightweight-2.6.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-shared/2.6/wagon-http-shared-2.6.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.7.2/jsoup-1.7.2.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/resolver/shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-archive/2.2.4/shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-archive-2.2.4.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/resolver/shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-maven-archive/2.2.4/shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-maven-archive-2.2.4.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus/0.3.0.M1/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.0.M1.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/jsr250-api-1.0.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.3.0.M1/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.0.M1.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/2.3/plexus-compiler-javac-2.3.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/2.3/plexus-compiler-api-2.3.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/2.53.1/selenium-java-2.53.1.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-edge-driver/2.53.1/selenium-edge-driver-2.53.1.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-safari-driver/2.53.1/selenium-safari-driver-2.53.1.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty/3.5.7.Final/netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:/home/ar/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-leg-rc/2.53.1/selenium-leg-rc-2.53.1.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 org.wildfly.swarm.howto.datasources.DatasourcesIT,testIt
May 04, 2017 9:53:16 PM org.jboss.arquillian.drone.webdriver.factory.remote.reusable.ReusedSessionPermanentFileStorage readStore
INFO: Reused session store is not available at /home/ar/.drone-webdriver-session-store, a new one will be created.
May 04, 2017 9:53:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: executable: /home/ar/projects/github/wildfly-swarm-howto/target/drone-phantomjs
May 04, 2017 9:53:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: port: 32428
May 04, 2017 9:53:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: arguments: [--webdriver=32428, --webdriver-logfile=/home/ar/projects/github/wildfly-swarm-howto/phantomjsdriver.log]
May 04, 2017 9:53:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: environment: {}
[INFO  - 2017-05-04T18:53:19.786Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 32428
[INFO  - 2017-05-04T18:53:20.249Z] Session [f1110070-30fa-11e7-af39-4f2ca589d1f5] - page.settings - {"XSSAuditingEnabled":false,"javascriptCanCloseWindows":true,"javascriptCanOpenWindows":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"loadImages":true,"localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled":false,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1","webSecurityEnabled":true}
[INFO  - 2017-05-04T18:53:20.250Z] Session [f1110070-30fa-11e7-af39-4f2ca589d1f5] - page.customHeaders:  - {}
[INFO  - 2017-05-04T18:53:20.250Z] Session [f1110070-30fa-11e7-af39-4f2ca589d1f5] - Session.negotiatedCapabilities - {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"2.1.1","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.2.0","platform":"linux-unknown-64bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}
[INFO  - 2017-05-04T18:53:20.250Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: f1110070-30fa-11e7-af39-4f2ca589d1f5

[INFO  - 2017-05-04T18:53:21.149Z] ShutdownReqHand - _handle - About to shutdown

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :Found the datasource
Actual   :
```

Comment: Are you just running the test from the howto project directly, or you imported it into your own project?

Comment: Ken, from the howto directly. `git clone https://github.com/wildfly-swarm/wildfly-swarm-howto.git`, then open with IDEA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that this particular example has modified the wildfly-swarm-plugin to start in the pre integration test phase: https://github.com/wildfly-swarm/wildfly-swarm-howto/blob/master/create-a-datasource/pom.xml#L102

When you run `mvn verify` on the command line the pre integration test phase will start WildFly Swarm before the test is executed.

If you wanted to run the test in the IDE, you would either need to start the project first, such as with `mvn wildfly-swarm:run`, or create a different unit test that essentially creates the WildFly Swarm container for the test.